# How do I condense and restructure data in R?

Tags: r

Sorry for the vague question title, but I really don't know how to explain this concisely.
I have some taxonomy (biology) data.

[image: here]

```
structure(list(phylum = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Acidobacteria", "Actinobacteria"), class = "factor"), 
    class = structure(c(3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("[Chloracidobacteria]", "Acidimicrobiia", "Acidobacteria", 
    "Actinobacteria", "DA052", "Solibacteres"), class = "factor"), 
    order = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Acidimicrobiales", "Actinomycetales", "Ellin6513", 
    "iii1-15", "RB41", "Solibacterales"), class = "factor"), 
    family = structure(c(NA, 4L, NA, NA, 5L, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 
    2L), .Label = c("[Bryobacteraceae]", "Brevibacteriaceae", 
    "Ellin6075", "RB40", "Solibacteraceae"), class = "factor"), 
    sample1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 18L), sample2 = c(0L, 
    6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sample3 = c(20L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

There are 5 samples total, which contain the quantity of different species of bacteria found within them. Each species is classified into phylum (broad), class, order, and family (narrow). For each of these groups, for example phylum, I'm trying to find the sum of the species that fall under that phylum, for each sample.

As an example: in sample1, there are `0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 7 + 0 + 6 + 0 = 13` species that are classified as "Acidobacteria", and then some "Actinobacteria", etc. How can I calculate these sums, then store them somewhere else so I can later make percentage stacked bar graphs like this one I made manually?

[image: this one]

I have no problems with that part; my main trouble is figuring out how to rearrange the data.

Basically, I'm trying to make different datasets for phylum, class, order, and family, and make a bar graph from each dataset. I've been told the dplyr package could help. I'm not very familiar with it, but after taking a look I don't see how any of the functions would help. I also thought about making several for loops that could sum the data in each phylum etc, but there are way too many categories when you move to more specific/narrower taxa.

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

phylum <- data %>%
  group_by(phylum) %>%
  summarise(sample_1_sum = sum(sample1),
            sample_2_sum = sum(sample2),
            sample_3_sum = sum(sample3)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(sample_1_sum, sample_2_sum, sample_3_sum),
               names_to = "Sample",
               values_to = "Values") 

ggplot(data = phylum, aes(x = Sample, y = Values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = phylum), position = "fill", stat = "identity")
```

with data being your data set. If you have a lot of sample columns to process I would approach it a little differently, but with just a couple of columns this is doable.

Result:

[image]

Comment: The code you provided worked, so thank you very much - but what is the purpose of %>%? I did a quick search and the answers were sort of confusing.

Comment: This is the so-called `pipe`. At the simplest level you can see it as the follows: say you have two functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`.  then `x %>% f %>% g` is equivalent to `g(f(x))`. So we start with object `x`, we then apply the function `f()` on `x`. The object that results from this operation is then passed to function `g()`. 

It is as if you 'pipe' the data from the left hand side function to right hand side function.

Off course, the real pipe is more complicated. It allows you to write elegant and easy to read code. There are many references on the internet.

Comment: The `pipe` was popularised in R in the `magrittr` package and later absorbed into the `tidyverse`. There is an insightful write-up on the magrittr page on the tidyverse website: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/